# Date picker in JQuery and php

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

I am implementing calendar using `JQuery`. This is the **pure html** form I tested and it's working fine.  But when I embed this in php, it's not working and the error shows up when I select inspect element is--> Object has no method datepicker.

**PURE HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Date Thing</title>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/start/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$( "#datepickerID" ).datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
})
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerID"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
 <?php
    include('sess.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.theme.css">

        <link href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/start/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

        $( "#datepickerID" ).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        })

        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" action="http://*****/******/redirect1.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="get">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerID"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone please let me know how to make that calendar work even in php code?

Comment: make sure that the js file not duplicating in whole the code, might possible there is conflicting js code, what kind of error your getting in error console ?

Comment: any other error in console.

Comment: @SagarPanchal the same error--> Object has no method datepicker. With php if you can provide working example.

Comment: @Jai No other error. Except this.

Comment: @rick check my answer. I already tested it. its working fine in my system.

Answer (score 0):

That generally means that you aren't loading the JQuery UI library. However, it looks like you are loading it twice. Perhaps try removing `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>`. It may be causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This in ypur PHP file .

```
<?php
    include('sess.php');
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $( "#datepickerID" ).datepicker({
                    changeYear: true,
                })
            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form name="form1" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="get">
                <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerID"></p>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```